# Unusual behavior with Ruby Queue and Typhoeus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, typhoeus

I'm having a very unusual behavior where the return obj of q.pop is not being updated accordingly. I'll demonstrate with psuedo-code...

```
q = Queue.new
insert unique objects into the q...

while !q.empty? do
    curr = q.pop
    req = Typhoeus::Request.new("someLegitURL")
    req.on_complete do |response|
        puts curr    #PROBLEM: same result every time!!!
    end
end
```

^Here, the problem I'm facing is that when i "puts curr", the object is the same every time!

If I replace the SAME code with an array like this:

```
arr = Array.new
insert unique objects into the arr...

arr.each do |curr|
    ... same thing ...
        puts curr    # NOT A PROBLEM: different result every time
    ... same thing ...
end
```

^Here, I actually get unique outputs for "puts curr".

Has anyone faced an issue like this?
Any insights into the problem / solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I'll answer my own question in case someone needs it later.

The problem: **Ruby's extremely unusual scoping with while loops.**

In a while loop in Ruby, each iteration of the loop doesn't die. Here's what I mean

```
while true
    i = 10
    break
end
puts i    # this will actually print out 10
```

However

```
loop do
    i = 10
    break
end
puts i    # raises error
```

In short: when I was using a while loop with a queue, the problem was that the iteration from the previous loop was not getting "wiped", thus affecting later iterations.

**When in doubt, use loop, not while.**